# How to travel between castles in the Loire valley?

Tags: transportation, france, castles, loire-valley

I'm planning to visit [Loire valley](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/823/chateaux-of-the-loire) and spend a week there. I know that I can travel from Paris to Tours by TGV, but I don't know what is the best way to explore the valley and visit individual castles. I don't need guided tours, I'm looking for a way to travel between the castles.

Comment: Since the castles are often far away and public transport will take a long time to get you there, I would suggest to rent a car.

Comment: Most of the castles aren't accessible by public transport at all, so it's either coach/tour, or car. (Or, if you want a more active vacation, bicycle! - though you'll only be able to catch about one chateau per day this way though, there's about 3 reachable from Tours, so you'd need to train-hop to different base towns. Car is your best bet otherwise.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A car is definitely a must have to visit the Loire valley. You have independence, and you can find some beautiful castles and view the country.

But you can go to some castles by train from Tours. Here are some examples:

- Chenonceaux: you can take the train from tours to Chenonceaux and
  walk to the castle. It can be beautiful because you have to cross
  the French garden.
- Blois: can be reached by [TER](http://www.ter-sncf.com/Regions/centre/fr/Default.aspx) (= regional train)
- Chambord: can be reached from Blois

For biking, you could visit [www.chateauxavelo.com](http://www.chateauxavelo.com/) or see [the map made by the tourism office](http://www.bloispaysdechambord.com/IMG/pdf/carteVelo-2011.pdf). The map is good but only available in French.

Answer (score 1):

Minibus is also a good option.

[Tour Evasion](http://www.tourevasion.com/prog_en.htm) ( the company I've traveled with ) has half-day tours ( two castles - approx 20-30 EUR ) and full-day tours ( four castles - approx 50 EUR ).

*Entrance fees are not included, but the prices are reduced.*