# What to do in the Loire region in France when you're tired of castles?

Tags: france, loire-valley

I already visited multiple castles in the Loire region in France and I really don't want to view more. What else can you do in the region? I've already been to a market in Beaugency, Blois, Tours and Orléans. Are there things that are less known and which are worth to visit? I don't really want to go further than Orléans or Tours, only if it's really worth it.

Comment: Have you canoed along the rivers there?  It provides a different aspect on the countryside.  Have you visited any of the vineyards for tastings?  Have you explored the goat cheeses produced in the area?

Comment: No, all of them not, suggest it as an answer!

Comment: non castle suggestions in my answer http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/832/46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you canoed along the rivers there? It provides a different aspect on the countryside.

Have you visited any of the vineyards for tastings?

Have you explored the goat cheeses produced in the area?

Comment: I'm definetly going to cano! :)

Comment: While you did say you were tired of castles, paddling the Cher River takes you literally right under and through Château de Chenonceau.

Comment: That doesn't matter, as long as I'm not in the castle